Overheating in the sleep mode 24.04.01 LTS
I have new Thinkbook-16 gen7 with intel core ultra 5. I have a problem when i suspend my laptop and put it in the bag, after some time it overheats and i can not wake it from suspend mode, neither with keyboard or touchpad. I have to turn it off with the power button then turn it on again. I am sure that there is some driver incompatibility. Is there any documentation about compatibility of Ubuntu 24.04.01 lts with these new generation cpu-s, and are there any news of upcoming updates for them?

That is a hardware problem as the OS is disabled when suspended. The BIOS is active and checks for events through its ACPI implementation. It might be USB power mode you are looking for; turn it off in your BIOS.

I turned it off, i'll see how it behaves tomorrow. Thank you!
